# Why is there datetime.datetime within Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I was wondering why there is datetime object in Pandas and it returns datetime.datetime exactly like datetime.datetime() does.

Datetime form Pandas:

```py
type( pandas.datetime(2019, 8, 1) )
```

returns

```py
datetime.datetime
```

Datetime from datetime:

```py
type ( datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 1) )
```

returns

```py
datetime.datetime
```

Is it for just for convenience or is there something special about datetime in Pandas?

Comment: Because developers realized that is is useful and they implemented some of the datetime library in pandas.  Like you said, `pandas.datetime` returns the same object as `datetime.datetime`

Comment: Yes it is just an alias.

Answer (score 2):

It is exactly a `datetime.datetime`.  To see why, try the following:

## foo.py

```
from datetime import datetime
```

## bar.py

```
import foo
print(foo.datetime)
```

You can probably see where this is going.  Since **foo.py** imported `datetime`, it is possible to access `datetime.datetime` through `foo`'s namespace, since it *exists* in `foo`'s namespace.

The exact same thing is happening with `pandas`.  See [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/35821a5794e434117b14797f010602c8e412b36c/pandas/__init__.py#L41).

Comment: Ok, so it's really the same datetime as in the datetime module and if the datetime module gets updated to a new version, I guess datetime in Pandas would be just referencing the new version.

Comment: Should be.  I wouldn't rely on the devs not changing `from datetime import datetime` to simply `import datetime` during a refactor though.